# Software architecture on linux, multithreading or multiprocrssing

Tags: linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, cortex-m

I have a linux running on an ARM cortex M4 processor (processor without MMU). I want to make an architecture for my software which will need to run multiple tasks in parallel (networking, touch screen, reading sensors...)

My question is: should I use multithreading or multiprocessing ? I think multiprocessing is not event possible with MMU-less processors. POSIX threads are included in my C-library (uclibc). Do you think using threads is a good solution for my architecture ?

I am comfortable with freertos, but I am a beginner on linux application development. I just want to be sure I am not missing important points.

Comment: You say you have Linux running. What makes you think that it can't run multiple processes? What have you tried? Linux without the ability to create new processes sounds about as useful as a bicycle without wheels.

Comment: I haven't tried anything for the moment. For the multiprocessing, I read that is it complicated without MMU (need to allocate "manually" the memory section for each process).

Comment: Yes, but you say you have Linux actually running. So, why _not_ try something? Experiment with it. See what your system can do. And, if it doesn't behave the way you expected it to behave, you can come back here and ask another question.

Comment: Thank you. I have another question now. I saw that when using a MMU-less linux (previously uclinux), fork() is replaced by vfork(). My question is why I can't compile some packages in buildroot due to the lack of MMU and especially the fork() ? If fork() is replaced by vfork(), I don't get why I cannot use these packages on my system.